# Is it possible to search for a particular string directly from a key binding, in TIG?

Tags: zsh, tig

Can you search for a specific string directly from a bound command?
I have a super-useful configuration – a bind to  that opens up this simple Zsh script on '%(text)' passed as 1st argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

emulate zsh -o extended_glob

if [[ $1 == (#b)([^:]##):([0-9]##):* ]]; then
    [[ -z $EDITOR ]] && EDITOR=mcedit

    $EDITOR +$match[2] **/$match[1];t
fi
```

It allows to open the compiler error-line by pointing cursor and pressing enter. It will automatically jump to the line with the error.

So, just run make within `tig` by `:!make` and browse all errors freely :)

However, I would need also a way to jump over to the errors, hence the question: how to search for "(error:|warning:)" directly via a key binding? I would like to bind it to `n` key in the pager view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
bind pager N :/\b(error|warning):
```

Similar to the default binding of `@` in diff view. Press `h` to find that binding in the help view.